# Can't access to miniDLNA

Tags: debian, vlc-media-player, dlna, upnp, debian-wheezy

I wanted to install a dlna server on my asus eeepc, and tried minidlna. My eeepc runs Wheezy, so I just had to run apt-get install to install minidlna on it.
The first time I ran it, everything worked fine, but once I restarted the service, I could never access it from VLC (running in Squeeze) again.

My config file:

```
media_dir=V,/home/media/vid
media_dir=P,/home/media/pic
media_dir=A,/home/media/aud

db_dir=/home/user/.minidlna
log_dir=/var/log

network_interface=wlan0
port=8200

inotify=no
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the right on the db directory and setting the right user:

```
chown -R user:user db_dir_path
chmod -R 755 db_dir_path
```